# Convert hover to toggle? Sorry if this is simple, I'm not a coder

Tags: javascript

I'll confess that I'm not a coder, I've gotten by from what I could glean from your answers to others' questions.  Here's my problem.  I'm trying to create dropdowns that are grids.  I've got it working for the most part, but I really need it to dropdown on click rather than hover.  From what I've ready I need to add jquery (?), but I don't know how to do that.  My non-profit can't afford to hire someone to fix this right now and I'm hoping one of you might be able to help.  Thank you in advance.  Here's what I have:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #003659;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #a10082;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 39%;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay,
.content.checked .content-overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ANTI-INFECTIVES (Including Antibiotics) 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antibiotics</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Amoxicillin<br>Amoxicillin/Clavulanate (Augmentin)<br>Cefdinir (Omnicef)<br>Cefadroxil (Duracef)<br>Cepdoxime (Vantin)<br>Cefuroxime (Ceftin)<br>Cephalexin (Keflex)<br>Ceprozil (Cefzil)<br>Ciprofloxacin (Cipro)<br>Dicloxacillin<br>Erythromycin<br>Nitrofurantoin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antivirals</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Acyclorvir<br>Rimantadine<br>Oseltavir (Tamiflu)<br>Valacylovir (Valtrex)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antifungals</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Clotrimazole<br>Ketoconazole<br>Moconazole<br>Nystatin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antifungal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Fluconazole (Diflucan)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">2 Week Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Azithromycin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Zithromax</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">2 Week Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">ALLERGY/COLD/ASTHMA
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Antihistamines (Non-Drowsy)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Cetirizine (Zyrtec)<br>Desloratadine (Clarinex)<br>Fexofenadine (Allegra)<br>Loratadine (Alavert, Claritin)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">No Waiting Period</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Montelukast</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Singular</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">No Waiting Period</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Antihistamines (Those That May Cause Drowsiness)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Chlorphaniramine<br>Diphenhydramine (Benadryl)<br>Doxylamine<br>**Diphenhydramine and doxylamine are also found in over-the-counter sleep medications such as Unisom, Zzzquil, Tylenol PM, Advil PM</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Cold Medications</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Dextromethorphan (Combination products such as Theraflu, Robitussin DM or CF)<br>Guaifenesin (Mucinex, Robitussin<br>Phenylephrine (Sudafed PE, Pseudoephedrine (Sudafed)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Albuterol</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Oral</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"hover to toggle"*

Comment: please describe better what you are looking for, there is too many possibility for what you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to toggle between hiding and displaying the dropdown elements on each user click, and Although it can be done in Vanilla JavaScript, but since you want jQuery here is a way to do that

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  $(this).children(".dropdown-content").toggle("visible");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #003659;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #a10082;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
}

dropdown-content.visible {
  display: block;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 39%;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay,
.content.checked .content-overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ANTI-INFECTIVES (Including Antibiotics) 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antibiotics</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Amoxicillin<br>Amoxicillin/Clavulanate (Augmentin)<br>Cefdinir (Omnicef)<br>Cefadroxil (Duracef)<br>Cepdoxime (Vantin)<br>Cefuroxime (Ceftin)<br>Cephalexin (Keflex)<br>Ceprozil (Cefzil)<br>Ciprofloxacin (Cipro)<br>Dicloxacillin<br>Erythromycin<br>Nitrofurantoin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antivirals</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Acyclorvir<br>Rimantadine<br>Oseltavir (Tamiflu)<br>Valacylovir (Valtrex)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antifungals</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Clotrimazole<br>Ketoconazole<br>Moconazole<br>Nystatin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antifungal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Fluconazole (Diflucan)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">2 Week Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Azithromycin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Zithromax</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">2 Week Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">ALLERGY/COLD/ASTHMA
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Antihistamines (Non-Drowsy)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Cetirizine (Zyrtec)<br>Desloratadine (Clarinex)<br>Fexofenadine (Allegra)<br>Loratadine (Alavert, Claritin)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">No Waiting Period</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Montelukast</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Singular</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">No Waiting Period</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Antihistamines (Those That May Cause Drowsiness)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Chlorphaniramine<br>Diphenhydramine (Benadryl)<br>Doxylamine<br>**Diphenhydramine and doxylamine are also found in over-the-counter sleep medications such as Unisom, Zzzquil, Tylenol PM, Advil PM</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Cold Medications</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Dextromethorphan (Combination products such as Theraflu, Robitussin DM or CF)<br>Guaifenesin (Mucinex, Robitussin<br>Phenylephrine (Sudafed PE, Pseudoephedrine (Sudafed)</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Albuterol</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">Oral</a>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of JavaScript (without jQuery) will help here :)

Note that I've also replaced the `:hover` CSS bit with `.dropdown-content.visible { display: block; }` (and for the sake of a shorter example, elided the actual lists of drugs).

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn")).forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const content = btn.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
    if (content) {
      content.classList.toggle("visible");
    }
  }, true);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #003659;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #a10082;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-content.visible {
  display: block;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 39%;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay,
.content.checked .content-overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ANTI-INFECTIVES (Including Antibiotics) 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      Go away bacteria!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ALLERGY/COLD/ASTHMA
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      Sneeze!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in vanilla javascript with one class and looping through the drop down elements and adding an event listener.

```
<style>
.show{display:block;}
</style>

    var dd = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
    dd.forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.target.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery. You can use basic JavaScript to accomplish that task.
What I had to do here was remove your original hover in CSS.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

I then added a new class into your CSS.

```
.dropdown-content-display {
  display: block;
}
```

I then wrote a bit of JavaScript to select the elements with the `dropbtn` class. Since there are two of them, I used `querySelectorAll` to select all elements with that class and set it to a constant variable called `dropBtn` (note the capital B) to indicate that this is a variable.

From there, I used a `forEach` method on `dropBtn` as it is a `NodeList` and functions similarly to an `array`.

With the `forEach` method, we are basically running an `anonymous function` on EACH ELEMENT that has the `dropbtn` class.

We then select the associated element with the class `dropdown-content` and set it to a new constant variable `dropDownCont`. We do this by moving UP the DOM to our element's parent Node, then using querySelector to find an element with the class `dropdown-content`. We do it this way so that querySelector is only checking for elements within our designated parent Node. In this case, that parent Node is the one right above our element with the class `dropbtn`. Alternatively, we could've used `nextElementSibling`.

From here, we just have a simple `if` statement asking if our `dropDownCont` has the class that we created earlier in our CSS (`dropdown-content-display`). If `dropDownCont` has this class, remove it. If it doesn't have this class, add it. That is basically our toggle.

```js
// Declare the constant variable dropBtn
// Set it equal to ALL elements with the class "dropbtn"
const dropBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn");

// For each element with the class "dropbtn"
dropBtn.forEach((element) => {
  // Add an event listener for a "click" and run an anonymous function
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Create a constant variable called "dropDownCont"
    // Set this const to the element with class ".dropdown-content"
    const dropDownCont = element.parentNode.querySelector(".dropdown-content");

    if (dropDownCont.classList.contains("dropdown-content-display")) {
      dropDownCont.classList.remove("dropdown-content-display");
    } else {
      dropDownCont.classList.add("dropdown-content-display");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #003659;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #a10082;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-content-display {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 39%;
}

.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.column a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content:hover .content-overlay,
.content.checked .content-overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ANTI-INFECTIVES (Including Antibiotics) 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antibiotics</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Amoxicillin<br>Amoxicillin/Clavulanate (Augmentin)<br>Cefdinir (Omnicef)<br>Cefadroxil (Duracef)<br>Cepdoxime (Vantin)<br>Cefuroxime (Ceftin)<br>Cephalexin (Keflex)<br>Ceprozil (Cefzil)<br>Ciprofloxacin (Cipro)<br>Dicloxacillin<br>Erythromycin<br>Nitrofurantoin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antivirals</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Acyclorvir<br>Rimantadine<br>Oseltavir (Tamiflu)<br>Valacylovir (Valtrex)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
      </div>
       </div>      
       <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antifungals</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Clotrimazole<br>Ketoconazole<br>Moconazole<br>Nystatin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antifungal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Fluconazole (Diflucan)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">2 Week Deferral</a>
        </div>
    </div>
           <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Azithromycin</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Zithromax</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">2 Week Deferral</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ALLERGY/COLD/ASTHMA
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antihistamines (Non-Drowsy)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Cetirizine (Zyrtec)<br>Desloratadine (Clarinex)<br>Fexofenadine (Allegra)<br>Loratadine (Alavert, Claritin)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">No Waiting Period</a>
        </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Montelukast</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Singular</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">No Waiting Period</a>
      </div>
       </div>      
       <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Antihistamines (Those That May Cause Drowsiness)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Chlorphaniramine<br>Diphenhydramine (Benadryl)<br>Doxylamine<br>**Diphenhydramine and doxylamine are also found in over-the-counter sleep medications such as Unisom, Zzzquil, Tylenol PM, Advil PM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Cold Medications</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Dextromethorphan (Combination products such as Theraflu, Robitussin DM or CF)<br>Guaifenesin (Mucinex, Robitussin<br>Phenylephrine (Sudafed PE, Pseudoephedrine (Sudafed)</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
    </div>
           <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Albuterol</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">Oral</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <a href="#">72 Hour Deferral</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</div>

</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```